# flowtype nullable object immutable property refinement

Tags: javascript, flowtype, nullable, refinement-type

I want to use refinement for a property that can be null. This object with the checked property then passed to function as an argument.

```
/* @flow */
const a: {+foo: ?string} = {};

const fun = (obj: {+foo: string}) => {
  return obj
}

if (a.foo) {
  fun(a) // null or undefined [1] is incompatible with string
}
```

[Try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5gCGAXGAN4DUUccpA-PgE4CWWA5gL5gC85HA3KgzZ8YKAFcsPMAAo4AIwBWpStVpgmrTgEoeAPnKowYRgFM84xlIWLUHIcyizCAOjW6yRsZJmFtd1CA)

It shouldn't work with an object with mutable property, because this property can be changed to `null` later. So that's why I use the immutable property. But it still doesn't work.

Is there a way to pass object with the refined property?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me since you can refine `a.foo: string` in the conditional and, as you said, the property is read only--I'd suggest opening an issue with the Flow project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refining a property of an object refines the property, not the object.

```
// `a.foo` is of type `?string`
// `a` is of type `{+foo: ?string}`
if (a.foo) {
  // within this block, `a.foo` is of type `string` (no `?`)
  // `a` is of type `{+foo: ?string}`
}
// `a.foo` is of type `?string`
// `a` is of type `{+foo: ?string}`
```

In this particular case, I would probably do something like this:

```
if (a.foo) {
  fun({ foo: a.foo });
}
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgbwNQDMQiQfmgJwEswBzAXxgF4UyBuAKHtElnQFcwqYAKEAIwBWSNJmwwCxcgEoqAPhT0YMfAFMobfJ34D6ZRoXQ84AOlEzkimOzDdkVrEhOiYZKQzJA))

Just because it's such a simple case. In a more complex case, you'd want to use [disjoint unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions).

```
type A = {
  +foo: string,
};

type B = {
  +foo: void,
};

type T = A | B;

const a: T = ({ foo: undefined }: B);

const fun = (obj: A) => {
  return obj
}

// `a` is of type `A | B` (which is type `T`)
if (a.foo) {
  // inside this block `a` is of type `A`
  fun(a);
}
// `a` is of type `A | B` (which is type `T`)
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUDUAzA9jgXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmANCgL4DcKKokUAQgsmprgSgA3HOQAm9Zq3bQAKjzgAfLixQBjHJRJQAhoXmIAFEigDCAV0piIWKhDFQGhTgEpVGrcFOWehnACMAK0IYFwQAPl50Ughgc1JKKADAxlYAejSoAAMdLKhyIiSsKBlspS48wwB3AAtyNRr8wtKs2SyXFHJiwx0AOgEw1HQM-K1xaGA6wv8AGxw1AGts3KaikvBoLJgsvixLHrdUkZy8grWW8s5K2vrGs5a2lyA))

At the end of the day, there is no super direct way to convert `{ +foo: ?string }` to `{ +foo: string }` because they are two completely different complex types, and must be handled as such.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using indirect casting, where you cast the type onto `any` because `any` accepts any type of value as an input. Then because the `any` type also allows you to read all possible types from it, you can assign the `any` value to your type because an `any` is also your type.

```
/* @flow */
const a: {+foo: ?string} = {};

const fun = (obj: {+foo: string}) => {
  return obj
}

if (a.foo) {
  fun((a: any))
}
```

Comment: It's an option, thanks. It can be reduced also to `fun((a: any))`. However, it seems like a dirty hack

Comment: i don't think there is any non "dirty" way to do it, other than changing the type of the function argument to accept null & undefined or making `foo` writable and assigning something like an empty string in case of null